# Linq to SQL query with paging optimization

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have a query that selects entries from a table that contains logging data. This table contains around 1 million data sets. The problem is that this query takes a long time to complete. I tried some variations of the query but performance is still poor especially for pages at the end.

```
Expression<Func<EventLogEntry, bool>> search = c => true;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
{
    search = c => c.Message.Contains(param.sSearch) ||
        c.Source.Contains(param.sSearch) ||
        c.Category.Contains(param.sSearch);
}

using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
{
    logs = db.Logs
        .Where(search)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp)
        .Skip(param.iDisplayStart)
        .Take(param.iDisplayLength)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Even with no search term the query takes a minimum of 10 seconds. Produced SQL looks like the following:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Extent1].[EventId] AS [EventId], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[EntryType] AS [EntryType], 
[Extent1].[Message] AS [Message], 
[Extent1].[Category] AS [Category], 
[Extent1].[Source] AS [Source], 
[Extent1].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
[Extent1].[Server_Id] AS [Server_Id]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[EntryType] AS [EntryType], [Extent1].[Message] AS [Message], [Extent1].[EventId] AS [EventId], [Extent1].[Category] AS [Category], [Extent1].[Source] AS [Source], [Extent1].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], [Extent1].[Server_Id] AS [Server_Id], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Timestamp] DESC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[EventLogEntries] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Timestamp] DESC
```

Is there any way to speed up this query?

Comment: Do you have indexes on the columns you filter by?

Comment: Adding .AsNoTracking() could also speed up the request

Comment: @neo The filter is not even applied in this scenario as the search term is empty. I just thought I'd add it to the code in case it may have impact on the query in some way I maybe oversee.

Comment: As well as indices on the columns you filter by, do you have one on the column you order by? Not having an index on `Timestamp` would make the query a lot more expensive than it should be.

Comment: Have you tried running the generated query in SSMS?

Comment: @SteveGreene Yes I did. It comes down to the same result.

Comment: Can you post the actual definition of the indices involved. Again, I'm particularly interested in that on `Timestamp` considering you find later pages to be worse than earlier.

Comment: @JonHanna I previously had no indices set. I now added an index to the timestamp column and performance greatly improved. Later pages are still worse but it is not as noticeable as before. Thanks for that advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indices are your friend. Which was discussed in the comments, but I'll add a bit more detail rather than having the question a zombie.

Because ordering is done on the basis of `Timestamp` and because the skipping and taking in turn relates to the order, putting an index on `Timestamp` will allow the server to speed up both that ordering and the pagination.

Indices on any columns used for filtering or joining would also help in general, but don't help so much with `Contains`-based filters.

If you'd later done a `Select()` so that only some columns were ultimately used, then a index with `Using` would help, e.g. if you had

```
`….Select(l => new {l.Id, l.EntryType, l.Message})`
```

Then an index on `Timestamp` that used `INCLUDE(Id, EntryType, Message)` would allow the query to be fulfilled from the index alone. This though isn't much of a gain when all columns are used, so you only get the down-side of a large index that uses a lot of space and slows down inserts. As such it's not of value here, but it is worth knowing about for how it benefits similar cases.

If possible also, avoid the `ToArray()` and instead process the results as they come. That gives faster time-to-first-result, faster overall time and less memory use.